# Have you used your daily votes?

Tags: discussion

As you can [see here in our TOP VOTERS list](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters), we simply have too less upvotes.

> Our main problem with this is, that we need a lot more users who have *more privileges*, so they can *actually help making the system better*. We need more people editing lame formatting, caring about tags, etc.

But that's not all:

> We need more votes on the really good questions, as the best will be forgotten and can't stand out of the crowd (of later and maybe not that good questions). Voting is marking stuff as *worth reading*.

And this is only possible with…

## …YOUR HELP!

So please **go and vote** from [the end](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions?page=386&sort=newest) to [the beginning](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Do not serial upvote

User's should be encouraged to use their votes and mark both questions and answers as **useful & well researched / lazy and of limited value** and **helpful / unhelpful**.

But a word of caution:

#### Do not just vote to use up all of your votes

- Doing so devalues the whole point of voting. +/- questions and answers that **you have read thoroughly** and feel deserve the vote.
- If a question or answer is sufficient bad to warrant a down vote. **Comment!** Provide useful feedback. This helps the OP and future visitors.
- If the average time you spend on a question/answer before voting it up is less than 30 seconds. **Stop**.

#### Do not just vote for people you know generally give good answers...

- In the words of Toscho

  > vote for content, not people
- We get new and infrequent users posting good answers or asking great questions <strike>every</strike> most days. Good content should be voted up!
- Case in point. Yesterday a user, meaning well, went round voting on a lot of answers - specifically my answers. While I'm sure each one deserved the upvote :), they did so at rate which meant they couldn't have given proper consideration to each one. To WPSE this looks like **serial upvoting**  - where you upvote a specific user lots of times in quick succession. This is not what votes are for, and does the community no good. **It's also pointless. WPSE reversed this upvotes, docking 210 points.**

## Vote... after consideration!

Comment: Well said :) Another quote by toscho: "If a question is worth answering, it's also worth an upvote".

Comment: Very good write-up. IMHO, a summary of it should arrive to the FAQ someday.

Answer (score 2):

#### Yes, I did!

<sup>Arriving at the mark of 600 Q up-votes haven't stopped me & I'm truly happy my first gold wasn't an Unsung Hero!</sup>

---

Going upwards as WordPress is going: *C'est ne pas possible!*...
One day or another this Stack will have to have a big boom of engaged users.

It's another level, I know, but hanging on StackOverflow is amazing for someone used to hang in here.
***Up and down votes fly as bullets in a Tarantino movie!***

Our day will come, Word-brothers and Press-sisters :o[)

Comment: Just clarifying, after reading Stephen answer: the Electorate badge motivated me more with a regular behavior I have: *always vote* when the Q or A is well thought/written and interesting/intriguing/didactic. Didn't know toscho's *content/people* words, but yes the *worth answer/upvote*: always nice to have in mind. If this Stack had a blog, it could have a Quote of the Day, or maybe we could open a `meta` like this `main`: [Best collection of Quotes for your Stack Q&A&C](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/best-collection-of-code-for-your-functions-php-file)?